# What is the equivalence class for this equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Suppose that $A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \}$. Let $R$ be the relation on the set $A$ such that $(x, y) \in R$ if and only if $x − y$  is an even integer. $R$ is an equivalence relation. What is the equivalence class for this equivalence relation?
My answer is $\{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 \}$, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your set is **an** equivalence class. There is another one, which is $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot!